# ItemCallback class is not found in android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil

Tags: android, paging, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to implement paging adapter in my project and end-up with a compilation error "Cannot resolve symbol 'ItemCallback'".

```
android {
            compileSdkVersion 27
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "*********"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 27
                ....
        }
dependencies { configuration ->
                implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
                implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
                implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
                implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
                implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
                ....
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the build.gradle. See what file the error message is referencing and post that code.

Comment: post your paging adapter code

Comment: @sasikumar I didn't even start writing the adapter. I have found this error while preparing the required members in order to create an adapter.

Comment: did you try clean and rebuild projects

Comment: @sasikumar Many times.

Comment: did you update all components in sdk manager ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried just now. Still no use.

Comment: I have found a hunch. I have mentioned implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1' but the import statement is being imported from 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'.